# Using str_count for multiple strings for "check all that apply" in survey data

Tags: r, string

Qualtrics' check all that applies produces per respondent a comma-separated cell with all the options each person clicked on. If I make a count table I get something like this, but with 10 unique choices:

| Combinations | Count |
| --- | --- |
| for news | 32 |
| for news, talk to friends | 7 |
| for news, find information | 14 |
| for news, talk to friends, find information | 5 |
| talk to friends | 55 |

I want to count each option so that for news = 32+7+14+5, talk to friends = 7+5+55 etc.
I can do `df$Var %>%  str_count("for news") %>% table()`  but this would have to be done 10 times. I am getting an error trying to mutate (`"Error in UseMethod("mutate") :  no applicable method for 'mutate' applied to an object of class "factor"`)

```
df$Var%>%mutate(news = str_count("for news"),
friends = str_count("friends"),
info = str_count("information"))
```

Do I have to `str_extract` using the comma, creating individual columns, and then `pivot_long` or is there a way to make different `str_count`s in one go?

Answer (score 1):

if space between each respondent, (for example, not `for news, talk to friends,find information`, like `for news, talk to friends, find information`) and let your data as `df`,

```
x <- rep(df$Combinations, df$Count)
x %>% str_plit(., ", ") %>% unlist %>% table

find information         for news  talk to friends 
              19               58               67
```

or by using `str_count`,

```
y <- c("for news", "talk to friends", "find information")
sapply(y, function(X) str_count(x, X)) %>% colSums()
str_count(x, "for news")

    for news  talk to friends find information 
          58               67               19
```

Answer (score 1):

Split the comma separated strings in new rows using `separate_rows` and for each `Combinations` , `sum` it's count.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  separate_rows(Combinations, sep = ',\\s*') %>%
  group_by(Combinations) %>%
  summarise(Count = sum(Count))

#  Combinations     Count
#  <chr>            <int>
#1 find information    19
#2 for news            58
#3 talk to friends     67
```

**data**

It is easier to help if you provide data in a [reproducible format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269) -

```
df <- structure(list(Combinations = c("for news", "for news, talk to friends", 
"for news, find information", "for news, talk to friends,find information", 
"talk to friends"), Count = c(32L, 7L, 14L, 5L, 55L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: I'm getting an error because count only exists if I first produce a table and rename it count, but `df %>%
  separate_rows(Var, sep = ',\\s*') %>%
  group_by(Var) %>% tally()` is doing the trick with the original data. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, that is why it is important to provide an example in a reproducible format. I am not sure how is your original `df` structured and with what column names. We only have the information that you share. I created a dataframe with the information that you showed and provided answer based on that.

Answer (score 1):

```
df %>%
  separate_rows(Var, sep = ',\\s*') %>%
  group_by(Var) %>% tally()
```